# Delete one in two rows in an ordered result set

Tags: mysql, delete, greatest-n-per-group

Is there a way to delete one in two rows in a result set using a single query?

E.g.

How to turn:

```
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| name        | gender | state | date        |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| John Kenedy | male   | NY    | 1540495296  |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| Meresa Oslo | female | HI    | 1540493940  |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| Another guy | male   | HI    | 1540492948  |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| Mike Lanes  | male   | FL    | 1540491974  |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

To this:

```
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| name        | gender | state | date        |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| Meresa Oslo | female | HI    | 1540493940  |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------+
| Mike Lanes  | male   | FL    | 1540491974  |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------------+
```

The process should go as follows:

1. Order the result set shown above by the `date` column, and then
2. Keep one row, delete the next one... keep one row, delete the next one...

I'd like to achieve that using a single query, if possible.

Comment: What is the primary key of the table? It would help if you added the SHOW CREATE TABLE output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to join the table with one combined with sequential numbers:

```
DELETE w.* 
  FROM table AS w
  NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT z.*
                      , IF(@cnt <> 0, @cnt:=0, @cnt:=1) AS cnt
                   FROM table AS z
                  ORDER BY z.date ASC
               ) AS q 
 WHERE MOD(q.cnt, 2) = 1
```

Also the same can be done by windowed function `ROW_NUMBER()` if `mysql` is  version 8+.

Comment: Replace `@cnt := @cnt + 1` with `@cnt := 1 - @cnt` and init `@cnt` with 0 (or 1) value in subquery's FROM clause. If so, it's enough to compare `@cnt` directly with 0 or 1 (dependent by the aim) and do not use MOD function.

Comment: @Akina Or `IF(@cnt <> 0, @cnt:=0, @cnt:=1) AS cnt` without any initialization.

Comment: Add `@cnt` initialization into your query - or the result will be unpredictable. If this variable not exists or is NULL - none records will be deleted. If @cnt is defined with non-number type value - the query will fail (dependent by the SQL Mode) or may delete wrong half of data (dependent by start value).  If it is not integer - nothing will be deleted... if it is integer - it may delete wrong half of data (dependent by start value). *Or `IF(@cnt <> 0, @cnt:=0, @cnt:=1) AS cnt` without any initialization* unnesessary overhead. Or query fail (dependent by SQL Mode).

Comment: @Akina SQL in opposite to the C initialize every UDV before first use by empty string. Therefore `<>` comparison with non-empty value is completely deterministic.

Comment: *SQL in opposite to the C initialize every UDV before first use by empty string.* **You're NOT right.** The question is marked with [mysql] tag. Open mysql console, execute `SELECT @cnt := @cnt + 1;` - you will understand that undefined variable auto-init value is NULL.

Comment: The proposed solution does not work. The result of the inner query gives NULL for all values of `cnt`. Consequently the `WHERE` clause never match and the resulting result is `Query OK, 0 rows affected (2.07 sec)`.

Comment: @quentinus95 I've edit my solution to fix a bug.

Comment: @Akina Yep, you're right, UDVs are implicitly set to the `NULL` so I've change the solution to the `IF(@cnt <> 0, @cnt:=0, @cnt:=1)` that is completely free of any initialization effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD id INT AUTO_INCREMENT ORDER BY date;
check that the ids are consecutive, etc
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id % 2 = 1;
optionally remove the column `id`
```